# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, curl, ssl-certificate

I create a php-curl file to akses API from another server:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://192.168.4.2/sdk_service/rest/users/login/v1.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:/xampp/htdocs/curl/cibinong/cacert.pem");
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "C:/xampp/htdocs/curl/cibinong/");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
print_r($result);
```

I got error message:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Help Me, maybe i miss something?

Comment: @MyNameIs IMO it indeed looks like the question, but the mentioned question does not seem to answer this one also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that you get an invalid SSL certificate, you need to turn off some checks. Can you try it with the following options?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

This will skips the verification of the SSL host and SSL peer. Because, that is what you need in this case.

Comment: Please mark this as the `solution` - that will give me some rep and also you let other users know that this was the answer. (Click the gray checkmark, below the +1 and -1)

Comment: Should be noted, turning it off opens you up to man in the middle attacks

Comment: It indeed does, but its also impossible to issue a trusted SSL certificate for an IP address. So we need to make a choice whether the security or usabillity is more important. (IMO)

Comment: Disabling the cert check is a work-around, not a proper fix. Don't settle with that.

Comment: It's not impossible. Use say, `mkcert` for your own certificate authority automatically (really easy, it's like a few commands) and then any certs generated from it are automatically trusted.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing a HTTPS URL using an IP address, which is very rarely actually working. Most sites require a name for SNI to be used to get the correct server cert and many CAs don't even sell you certs for plain IP addresses.

Instead of disabling the cert-check you should consider accessing this server using its "proper" and offical name so that the server knows which cert to offer in the TLS handshake.

If you really want to connect to this specific IP address and still use the right name in the URL, you can do so with the `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` option. Documented among the other CURL options.

Don't settle with disabling the cert-check. That's a poor work-around that only risks sticking around forever and makes you vulnerable.